# How to make the right brace on the same line in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

How to configure WebStorm to place parenthesis on the same line when formatting is triggered(<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd>)? It currently formats in this way:

```js
const {
  onError = () => {
  },
} = props
```

and I want it to format like that

```js
const {
  onError = () => {},
} = props
```

Can not find it in WebStorm's preferences: `Settings -> Code Style -> JavaScript -> Wrappings and Braces` shows nothing relevant. The `Braces placement` only can change the left brace.

Comment: I doubt it is possible without external formatter like Prettier.

Comment: Check the checkbox for `Simple methods in one line` option.

Answer (score 0):

Set the checkbox for `Simple methods in one line` option. It also works in PhpStorm.

[image: Show screenshot]